# Binary Search Tree pre-, in-, post-order traversal for given tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree, tree-traversal

I have Binary Search tree and have to perform three types of tree traversal:
Are this results correct?

```
Pre-order (root,left,right): 30,15,59,43,40,92

In-order (left,root,right): 15,30,59,40,43,92

Post-order (left,right,root): 15,59,40,43,92,30
```

[image]

---

UPDATE:

**In-order:** 15,30,40,43,59,92 (projection?)

**Post-order:** 15,40,43,92,59,30.

Is it right?

Comment: …and, regardless of any image, do 15,30,59,10,43,92 look 'in-order' by any means?

Comment: `10` meant to be `40`.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts by deleting them.

Comment: Thanks for comment but otherwise I will get a lot of down votes while the problem being is dumb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given this updated tree, your preorder traversal is correct.

Your inorder traversal, though, is incorrect. As a hint, doing an inorder traversal of a binary tree always lists the values off in sorted order.

Finally, your postorder traversal is incorrect. The value 59 won't be produced until after all of the nodes in its two subtrees are produced, so it should come second-to-last. Using this fact, try seeing if you can come up with the correct answer.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is the last update has right answers for In-order and Post-order tree traversal?